# Android アプリ開発での Intentを使ったカメラ連携でのエラー　Permission？

Tags: android, java, camera

ほんきで学ぶAndroidアプリ開発入門という本でAndroid開発を学んでいます
今はIntentを使ったアプリの連携を学んでいるのですが、
カメラを使う連携でどうしてもエラーが出てしまいます。
オプションメニューで選ばれたときにカメラを呼び出し、写真を撮り
撮った写真を表示するというプログラムなのですが、
まずMainActivity.javaに次のようなコードを追加しました

```
private Uri mImgUri;
```

/**/

```
if(itemId == R.id.action_camera){
                String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
                Log.v("test",fileName);
                mImgUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImgUri);
                Log.v("test","test1");
                startActivityForResult(intent,100);
            }

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode ==100){
            //ImageViewに表示する場合
            ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            imageView.setImageURI(mImgUri);
        }
    }
```

そしてAndroidManifest.xmlに次の→　←の所のコードを追加しました

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kayosystem.honki.chapter06.lesson25" >

→   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> 　←

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
```

このプログラムを実行したとき出るエラーは次の通りです

```
02-13 15:31:53.306 14237-14237/com.kayosystem.honki.chapter06.lesson25 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kayosystem.honki.chapter06.lesson25, PID: 14237
  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14237, uid=10364 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1688)
      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:482)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1277)
      at com.kayosystem.honki.chapter06.lesson25.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:95)
      at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3245)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:406)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:667)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1219)
      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3191)
      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4139)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6223)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

エラーが出ているのはMainActivity.javaの

```
mImgUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

このコードのところでおきているようです。

自分で調べて見た所、パーミッションが無いといわれており、AndroidManifest.xmlにパーミッションを追加すればいいらしいのですが、うまくいきません

どなたかご助言お願いいたします。

Comment: 書き忘れておりました。使っているソフトはAndroid Studio2.2.3で実行しているのはSony SOV33 Android7.0,API21です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGEの様なPermissionはDangerousPermissionと呼ばれており、
Manifestへの記載のほか(Android6.0以降では)ユーザーの許可が必要です。

実装方法の詳細は下記に記載されておりますが。
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

とりあえず動くところを試したいのであれば
設定＞アプリ＞(目的のアプリタップ)＞権限
から許可してあげれば動くと思います。

Comment: なるほど！ユーザーの許可が必要だったのですね！とりあえず権限で許可した所無事動きました！
教えていただけなければ絶対にたどり着けなかったところでした。
有難うございます！

Comment: リンク先のページを読んでいただければわかると思いますので蛇足とは思いますが、通常はアプリからユーザーへの許可を促す実装をするべきで、設定からのルートは「とりあえず」動かすための方法です。また、問題が解消されたならばチェックマーク✔をクリックして質問を終了していただければと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
チェックボックスの存在に気づいていませんでした
リンク先のページを参照して許可を促す実装をしてみます