# Androidでassets内のpdf を開きたい

Tags: android, pdf

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    File fileBrochure = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "abc.pdf");
    if (!fileBrochure.exists())
    {
         CopyAssetsbrochure();
    } 

    /** PDF reader code */
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "abc.pdf");      

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try 
    {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
    {
         Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//method to write the PDFs file to sd card
    private void CopyAssetsbrochure() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try 
        {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            String fStr = files[i];
            if(fStr.equalsIgnoreCase("abc.pdf"))
            {
                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                try 
                {
                  in = assetManager.open(files[i]);
                  out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + files[i]);
                  copyFile(in, out);
                  in.close();
                  in = null;
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();
                  out = null;
                  break;
                } 
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                } 
            }
        }
    }

 private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
          out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

のようにしてもabc.pdfが開けませんとでます。どうすればいいのでしょう？

Comment: コードを選択して`{}`ボタンを押すとコードをハイライトできますご活用ください。

Comment: `assetManager.open(files[i]);`
や
`copyFile()`
まで進んでいる事は確認できていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ソースから2点気になりました

・RuntimePermission関連のソースがありませんが、
　ExternalStorageに保存しているので必要なはずです。
　Manifestファイルにpermissionの設定およびRuntimePermissionの許可は行っていますでしょうか？
　参考：[Android アプリ開発での Intentを使ったカメラ連携でのエラー　Permission？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32624)

・file://スキーマでのIntent受け渡しはAndroid7.0よりできなくなっています。
　参考：https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html?hl=ja
　AndroidのVersionはいくつでしょうか？

---

追記：
ご提示のソースから
RuntimePermissionの設定
および
file://スキーマをcontent://に変更したところpdfファイルの読み込み(他Activityへの受け渡し)ができました。

・RuntimePermissionについて
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

・アプリ間のファイル共有について
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html